# PHP parsing stops

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse pages. I've read that it needs to set a header to avoid a 500 server error So I did.

But what happens is after 5 or so pages, the parsing stops. No error it just stops.

The code:

```
$url = 'http://www.someurlhere.com';
$options = array('http' => array('header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4"));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
```

edit

```
        foreach($html->find('table.votes tr.even,tr.odd') as $tr) {
            if ($tr->find('td', 3) == '<td>absent</td>') { 
              $absent = $absent + 1; 
            }
            $possible = $possible + 1;
        }
        echo 'absent=> ' . $absent . ' out of => ' . $possible . '<br>';
```

Comment: I don't see you parsing anything in the code you posted

Comment: edited to add the code

Comment: Probably a timeout by the web server...!? You shouldn't do long running tasks in a browser/through a web server. This probably calls for a background task/queue-worker/CLI script.

Comment: @deceze parsing stops after 5 or so pages. parsed the same type of page just getting different data and was able to process 50 pages without an issue. so i'm stumped